# Poisson GLM with rare outcome (very negative coefficient)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, zero-inflation, rare-events

Suppose I have the model
\begin{align*}
Y_i \sim \text{Poisson}(e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1t_i + \beta_2X_i + \beta_3 t'_i})
\end{align*}
where $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (-1, 0, -10, 0)$ for $t_i = i$ for $i = 1, \cdots, 100$, $X_i = \mathbb{I}(t_i \ge 60)$, and $t_i' = \max(0, t_i - 60)$. You can imagine a scenario where we are observing some count outcome for 100 weeks; at week 60, an intervention occurs and is super effective at eliminating any count outcomes (with $\beta_2 = -10$). We regress against $t_i$ and $t_i'$ to capture the temporal effects before and after intervention, albeit in this example there are no temporal effects.

Here is a reproducible example of simulating from this model and fitting with a Poisson GLM in R:

```
beta0 = -1
beta1 = 0
beta2 = -10
beta3 = 0

t = 1:100
X = (t >= 60)*1
t_prime = pmax(0, t - 60)

lambda = exp(beta0 + beta1*t + beta2*X + beta3*t_prime)
Y = rpois(100, lambda)

dat = data.frame(Y = Y, t = t, X = X, t_prime = t_prime)
mod = glm(Y ~ t + X + t_prime, data = dat, family = poisson)
summary(mod)

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -9.412e-01  4.093e-01  -2.299   0.0215 *
t            3.982e-03  1.153e-02   0.345   0.7298  
X           -1.860e+01  2.891e+03  -0.006   0.9949  
t_prime     -3.982e-03  1.244e+02   0.000   1.0000
```

We see that testing for $\beta_2 \neq 0$ is very insignificant, while clearly $\beta_2$ is very different from 0. The reason for this insignificance stems from having absolutely no outcomes once the intervention is in place, in which case the model can't differentiate between something like $\beta_2 = -10$ or $\beta_2 = -100$, all of which result in $\exp(\beta_2) \approx 0$, and results in large standard errors. How can I correctly test for the significance of $\beta_2$?

Answer (score 0):

If this is how your data is generated, you need way more data to be able to pick up the effect of `X`. If you are interested in significance testing of GLMs, there is a good paper by Lyles (2006) *A practical approach to computing power for generalized linear models with nominal, count, or ordinal responses*. There's probably an implementation in R somewhere.

However, it may be that in a real life context, there are better (or at least, different) ways of describing the data. For example, a zero-inflated Poisson model, where `X` is a predictor variable for the zero-inflated term. Whether you think this is appropriate should hopefully be dictated by theory.